# Google App Script from secondary gmail account

Tags: google-apps-script, http-status-code-400

I created a second email address from my existing gmail account.  I have a test form and a test sheet in the secondary drive but I can not access the Google App Script editor from the secondary account. I receive

> This page isn’t working, ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

then

> Bad Request Error 400

How do I enable this?

Comment: How did you create your second email address from your existing Gmail Account? Did you follow this [article](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27441) to create another Google account? Or, did you create an alternate email address on your [account settings](https://myaccount.google.com/email)?

Comment: To be honest, I don't recall.  But both accounts show only one email associated with them.

Comment: Possibly, this issue might be related to this issue if you are logged into multiple Google Accounts 

[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/projects\#fix-issues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/projects#fix-issues)

Comment: Request access  from secondary and accept it in primary account?

Comment: @TheMaster I snooped around but couldn’t find where I do that. Could you be more specific? Thanks.

Comment: `but I can not access` Was there a error message?

Comment: “This page isn’t working, ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS” then “Bad Request Error 400”

Comment: Figured it out. I was signed into both accounts. Had to log out completely and then log in to the secondary account. Thanks for your help.